# Javascript+Css, request solution: mouseover hover displays div, stays active until mouseoff/click closes

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, mousehover

Okay, so: I am trying to put an infobox-sort of thing on my page. The basic idea is as follows:

- person mouses over brown curved-cornered tab. Tab changes color to white, becomes square, and box of info about that tab appears.
- as long as mouse remains over that tab or over related box of info, tab remains white and square, and related box of info remains open.
- person mouses off of tab and related box. Box closes, tab returns to brown and curvy.

So far, I have managed to make the brown tabs turn white if hovered, and the box of info appears. it remains white and the info stays open. However, I cannot figure out two things:

**- how to make the corner tabs change their shape on mouseover and then revert once moused off**
*-- have only managed through various tests to make it either permanently brown/round, or white/square, no switching.*

**- how to make the infobox and tab color/shape revert to normal brown/curvy/invisible once moused off.**

I have been using the w3school How-tos and some stackoverflow threads to get this far, but I've hit a wall and I don't remember enough javascript to figure out what I've got wrong. I hope I'm providing enough information for assistance.

If possible, I need a solution in CSS/Javascript. Most possible solutions I've seen are in jquery, which I'm even more baffled by. However, if there is an easier solution to all my problems that I have somehow missed, I am very open to learning it.

**For reference, here is my code:**

the css of my page:

```
/* Style the containment unit*/
.tabcontainer {
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid #BB8571;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    min-height:200px;

}

/* Style the tabs*/
.tabcontainer button {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;

}

.tabcontainer button:nth-child(even) {background:#d7b8ac;}
.tabcontainer button:nth-child(odd) {background:#f4dac3;}

/* Change background color of tabs on hover and maintain change while active */
.tabcontainer button:hover, .tabcontainer button.active {
    background-color:#fff;
}

/*specific corner tab styling*/
.tabcontainer button:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.tabcontainer button:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    }

/* Style the infoboxes */
.tabcontent {
    display:none;
    background-color:tan;
    padding:2em 1em 1em;
    height:170px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

the html of my page:

```
<div class="tabcontainer"> <!––wraps around both tabs and info boxes-->

 <!––below: bar of button tabs--> 

<button class="tablinks" id="t1" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b1')">b1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t2" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b2')">b2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t3" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b3')">b3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t4" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b4')">b4</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t5" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b5')">b5</button>

<!––below: five infoboxes with generic contents-->

<div id="b1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="b2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="b3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>LA</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="b4" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>NYC</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="b5" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

and the javascript of my page, which as you can see is heavily notated as I try to figure out how the heck it works.

```
//start infoBox function to open infobox of a tab, concerning event and affected 'tab id'
function infoBox(event, tabID) {
//declare variables of i=data, tabcontent=blurb, tablinks=buttons
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
// find variable=tabcontent as anything with class 'tabcontent'
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
// hide variables of tabcontents   
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
// find variable=tablinks as anything with class 'tablinks'    
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
// remove active status of tablinks   
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
// show the current onmouseover tab
    document.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";
// related named target of event infobox, activate and show   
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You need also function to remove the info tabs on `mouseout`. They won't automagically *"un-onmouseover"* themselves :-) And while doing that, also remove `.active` class;

Working code:

```js
function infoBox(event, tabID) {
//declare variables of i=data, tabcontent=blurb, tablinks=buttons
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
// find variable=tabcontent as anything with class 'tabcontent'
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
// hide variables of tabcontents   
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
// find variable=tablinks as anything with class 'tablinks'    
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
// remove active status of tablinks   
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
// show the current onmouseover tab
    document.getElementById(tabID).style.display = "block";
// related named target of event infobox, activate and show   
    event.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function closeInfoBox() {
 var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    // hide tabcontents   
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // remove also active class
    var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
}
```

```css
.tabcontainer {
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid #BB8571;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    min-height:200px;

}

/* Style the tabs*/
.tabcontainer button {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    transition: all .5s;

}

.tabcontainer button:nth-child(even) {background:#d7b8ac;}
.tabcontainer button:nth-child(odd) {background:#f4dac3;}

/* Change background color of tabs on hover and maintain change while active */
.tabcontainer button:hover, .tabcontainer button.active {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

/*specific corner tab styling*/
.tabcontainer button:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.tabcontainer button:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    }

/* Style the infoboxes */
.tabcontent {
    display:none;
    background-color:tan;
    padding:2em 1em 1em;
    height:170px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tabcontainer"> <!––wraps around both tabs and info boxes-->

 <!––below: bar of button tabs--> 

<button class="tablinks" id="t1" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b1')" >b1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t2" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b2')" >b2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t3" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b3')" >b3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t4" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b4')" >b4</button>
      <button class="tablinks" id="t5" onmouseover="infoBox(event, 'b5')" >b5</button>

<div id="b1" class="tabcontent" onmouseleave="closeInfoBox()">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="b2" class="tabcontent" onmouseleave="closeInfoBox()">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="b3" class="tabcontent" onmouseleave="closeInfoBox()">
  <h3>LA</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="b4" class="tabcontent" onmouseleave="closeInfoBox()">
  <h3>NYC</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="b5" class="tabcontent" onmouseleave="closeInfoBox()">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm seeing what you did and I like it! However, in your suggestion, the infobox disappears when I stop mousing over the related tab. I need the tab to stay white AND the box to be visible until I move the cursor away entirely. The idea is there will be links and things in the infobox that someone might click.

Comment: @kesomon Hi, I've edited the code. I didn't realize what effect you wanted. So the new solution is to move `onmouseleave` attribute to the big tabcontents. Now it should be what you were looking for.

Comment: That's perfect! Clearly, I need to read up on the less-well-advertised event options, I didn't even remember onmouseleave was a thing. Thank you so much!